# Parsing one col of multiple rows php

Tags: php, mysql

I have e.g. the following data returned from a query, each name is an item:

```
id      name      comment
1       FF        hey
1       FF        hey back!
2       LL         
3       PP        i think its great!
3       PP        me too
3       PP        I'm not sure
4       TT         
5       II      
6       KK        yesterday is the new tomorrow
```

When I display it, each 'item' has an id and are displayed in DIVs use LI.

As you can see though there are multiple comments sometimes for an 'item', each on a separate line

What I want to do is display each item and then show comments under each item if there are any. So, i can't group by anything at query stage as the comment section is unique, but need to group at display stage

So currently have:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<li><div class=className><div class=itemName>'.$row[name].'</div>';

    if($row[comment]){ 

       echo '<div class=newRow>'.$row[comment].'</div>'; 

    }

echo '</div></li>';

}
```

Now, this is no good because this will produce multiple displays for the same item with one comment under each.

Can I do this or should I bring in the data differently?

The ideal result is e.g.

```
FF             LL             PP                       etc etc etc
hey                           i think its great!
hey back!                     me too
                              I'm not sure
```

Comment: as the first line says, each name is an item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on your mysql query to group all the comments together for each name

```
SELECT id, name
GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS comment
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

then [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the `$row[comment]` in your php code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<li><div class=className><div class=itemName>'.$row['name'].'</div>';

    if($row['comment'] != ""){

       $comments = explode(",",$row['comment']);
       foreach($comments as $comment){
               echo '<div class=newRow>'.$comment.'</div>';
       } 

    }

echo '</div></li>';

}
```

**Edit**
Thanks to @CBroe, I now know that `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) default of 1024. You will want to increase this before running the `GROUP_CONCAT()` query -

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = 10240; // must be in multiples of 1024
SELECT id, name
GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS comment
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

you will also need to be aware of [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) as this is the limit you can set `var_group_concat_max_len` to.

note: `mysql_query()` does not allow multiple queries, so you will need to do 2 `mysql_query()`, and you can use `SET SESSION ...` so that all queries in your current session have that `max_len`. It would be better to change from `mysql_` functions (which are depreciated) and change to [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as they offer multiple query option. also check out - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Nice database-based grouping solution.

Comment: Kepp in mind: _"The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable, which has a default value of 1024."_ (From MySQL docs.) So if comments is meant to be something like the comment system here, 1024 characters can be hit by only a handful of comments. And even for shorter comments, one might easily hit this limit if there are many.

Comment: @CBroe Damn! Thanks for pointing that out, this was a great solution until you mentioned that

Comment: @CBroe Did not know this, but that is just the default as it says *The value can be set higher ...* by using syntax [`SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)  *This value by default is small, to catch large (possibly incorrect) packets. You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use.*

Comment: I have updated my answer referencing `group_concat_max_len` and how to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse data access with output and you will have an easier time attacking this sort of problem.

```
//Fetch and Sort
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $item = $row['item'];
   if(!isset($data[$item]) {
     $data[$item] = array():
   }
   $data[ = $data[$item][] = $row['comment'];   
}

//Output
foreach($data as $item => $comments) {
    echo '<li><div class=className><div class=itemName>'.$item.'</div>';
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
      echo '<div class=newRow>'.$comment.'</div>'; 
    }
    echo '</div></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting the data back sorted by id already, add to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY name
```

which will retrieve the same list ordered by id. Then in your while loop, add a variable that keeps track of the last item name that you saw. If it changes, add a new li, otherwise, add the comment on to the end of your current list.

Comment: I think you mean sort by name, then by ID. Otherwise (7,FF,Some comment) will break your system.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse I thought id was tied to name. Fixed