# SQL JOIN - Need to return one product id but all variations of it (e.g. Size, colour)

Tags: php, sql

I have several tables I'm joining to display my product details from a stock table.  Therefore, one product ID can have many entries in the stock table due to multiple colours and sizes.

Table 1: `tblStock`

```
stockID
productID
sizeID
colourID
qty
```

Table 2: `tblColour`

```
   colourID 
   colourName
   colourHEX
```

Table 3: `tblSize`

```
   sizeID
   sizeName
```

My query:

```
    SELECT p.productID, c.colourName, c.colourHEX, sz.sizeName, s.qty
    FROM tblProducts p
    INNER JOIN tblStock s ON p.productID = s.productID
    INNER JOIN tblColour c ON s.colourID = c.colourID
    INNER JOIN tblSize sz ON s.sizeID = sz.sizeID
    WHERE p.productID = '$id'
```

is returning:

```
   productID   colourName   colourHEX   sizeName       qty
   4           Burgundy     #621b40     Small          10
   4           Burgundy     #621b40     Medium         15
   4           Burgundy     #621b40     Large          20
   4           Pink         #ba0046     Large          20
```

Is there any way that I can only return the product ID once but keep all it's variations?

If not, how would I echo this product to the page as I don't want it to appear 4 times.  Just appear once with the various options available detailed.

Comment: `if ($currentId != $lastId) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Same answer as here, with the same caveat as mentioned in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462408/parsing-one-col-of-multiple-rows-php/15462607#15462607

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT p.productID, group_concat(distinct c.colourName), group_concat(distinct c.colourHEX), group_concat(distinct sz.sizeName), sum(s.qty)
FROM tblProducts p
INNER JOIN tblStock s ON p.productID = s.productID
INNER JOIN tblColour c ON s.colourID = c.colourID
INNER JOIN tblSize sz ON s.sizeID = sz.sizeID
WHERE p.productID = '$id'
group by p.productID ;// group by required only if you product id clause is removed
```

Comment: Using PHP how do I access the individual results from this  query?  For example. I need to echo the number of small items and the colour?

Comment: it return only on row, u can give an alias name for each column to access in php as , **group_concat(xxx) AS COL1**. After fetching the row, do a print_r/ var_dump to identify the keys generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to PHP but your problem is very simple.

All you need is a separate variable inside a loop like this:

```
sql="SELECT p.productID, c.colourName, c.colourHEX, sz.sizeName, s.qty"
sql=sql+"FROM tblProducts p"
sql=sql+"INNER JOIN tblStock s ON p.productID = s.productID"
sql=sql+"INNER JOIN tblColour c ON s.colourID = c.colourID"
sql=sql+"INNER JOIN tblSize sz ON s.sizeID = sz.sizeID"
sql=sql+"WHERE p.productID = '$id'"

Set rs = RecordSetForStoringSQLQueryResult -- Replace with appropriate code in PHP
rs.Open (connectionName, sql)

$prevProductID = Null; -- Or some other number
while not rs.EndOfFile
    $currentId = rs("productID")
    if ($currentId != $lastId) {
         -- New ID found, display it.
         echo($currentId); 
         $prevProductID = $currentId
    } else { 
         -- Code for logic when the current product ID is same as previous product ID
         -- You will not assign anything to $prevProductID in this section.
    }
    rs.MoveToNextRecord
end while
```

Kindly consider that I am not a PHP guy, but I have done similar things in classic ASP. The code above is just for illustration purposes and it is not directly usable. You will need to tweak it as per your plan.

Comment: i,ll give this a go.  i tried grouping by id and distinct id. hadn,t tried the other way round

Comment: Yes, and do note that his is not a directly useable code. Try to understand the logic and code in PHP properly. I hope you get the solution you are looking for. This is in fact difficult for a newbie but very simple if you have enough experience.