# How to output product variations

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop

I would like some advice on how best to approach outputting multiple products and their variations from a database.

I am building an eCommerce application and need to output a series of products and their product variations (colour, size).

My database has:

- Table 1: ProductID, ProductTitle, ProductImg, ProductCat
- Table 2: ProductID, ProductSize, ProductColour

**Foreign key on ProductID**

My current code is this:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['cat']; // this pulls the category from URL param

include 'db_connect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductTitle, a.ProductImg, b.ProductColour 
                              FROM product_info AS a 
                                JOIN product_options AS b ON a.ProductID=b.ProductID 
                              WHERE a.ProductCat = '".$q."'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<div class='product-display'>";

        echo "<img id='prodImage' src='Images/" . $row['ProductImg'] . ".jpg' alt='product photo'>";
        echo "<h3>" . $row['ProductTitle'] . "</h3>";
        echo "<h3>" . $row['ProductColour'] . "</h3>";

    echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

This outputs:

- Product 1, Colour 1
- Product 1, Colour 2
- Product 2, Colour 1
- Product 2, Colour 2
- Product 3, Colour 1
- Product 3, Colour 2

I want it to output:

- Product 1, Colour 1, Colour 2
- Product 2, Colour 1, Colour 2
- Product 3, Colour 1, Colour 2

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

FYI - my array output is this:

- Array ( [ProductTitle] => Puffer Jacket [ProductImg] => 444 [ProductColour] => Aubern )
- Array ( [ProductTitle] => Puffer Jacket [ProductImg] => 444 [ProductColour] => Black )
- Array ( [ProductTitle] => The Bander [ProductImg] => 111 [ProductColour] => Aubern )
- Array ( [ProductTitle] => The Bander [ProductImg] => 111 [ProductColour] => Black )
- Array ( [ProductTitle] => The comfy one [ProductImg] => 222 [ProductColour] => Aubern )
- Array ( [ProductTitle] => The comfy one [ProductImg] => 222 [ProductColour] => Black )

**SOLUTION:**

Please refer to:

[Parsing one col of multiple rows php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462408/parsing-one-col-of-multiple-rows-php/15462607#15462607)

and

[SQL JOIN - Need to return one product id but all variations of it (e.g. Size, colour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463666/sql-join-need-to-return-one-product-id-but-all-variations-of-it-e-g-size-co)

These answer it nicely... problem solved.

Comment: Do you want to do this with PHP or directly with SQL

Comment: With php. The parameter 'q' is set from an option drop down on my main products page. JavaScript is then used to grab this code an update a div to display the products